# Trouble with converting function to a one line list comprehension

Tags: python, functional-programming

Could someone explain to me the correct solution for converting this function to a one line list comprehension?

```
def get_files(directory):
    filepaths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
           filepaths.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return filepath
```

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work (NameError, name 'files' not defined)

```
def get_files(directory):
    return [os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in files for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory)]
```

Comment: I think the multiline version is more readable. But it's probably better to make it a generator

Comment: @John: It would be possible to make it a one-line generator expression. Regardless, I agree it should be some sort of generator.

Comment: @martineau, once we get permission exceptions or need to skip some directories or need to write a unit test, we start extracting these pieces as functions/generators anyway. The generator is only 4 lines long. A generator expression will use 2 lines unless you choose short variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` statements are in the wrong order. Try:

```
[os.path.join(root, filename) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory)
                              for filename in files]
```

Comment: Good answer, documentation can be found here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions